# EF 4 EDMX to 6 Upgrade. Issue with SaveChanges for new record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have upgraded my EF 4 EDMX implementation to EF 6. Followed all the help from SO & MSDN & now I am generating all models based on T4 code generation template.

Everything is working as it is supposed to be with only one exception. For one of the module, when a new entity is created, object context's  `_objectContext.SaveChanges();` method doesn't create a new record in the database. It is also not throwing any errors.

We have used a "Unit of Work" pattern. In the same context, I am updating the last modify date of other tables & bunch of other updates. I see, those are reflected properly.

When I try to trace the generated SQL queries with

```
_objectContext.InterceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault().Database.Log = x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);
```

I see all the SQL update statements. But, I don't see Insert into system for the model I created. I tried to drop & re-add the table in EF, that didn't help. What I am missing here? How can I debug to find the actual cause?

Edit: Adding code

```
public partial class ProjectNameContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectNameContext()
        : base("name=ProjectNameContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    .......
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}


public class EntityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter : IObjectContext
{
    private readonly ObjectContext _objectContext;

    public EntityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter(ProjectNameContext context)
    {
        _objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        //_objectContext.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(objContext_SavingChanges);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _objectContext.Dispose();
    }
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _objectContext.InterceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault().Database.Log = x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);
        _objectContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IObjectSet<T> CreateObjectSet<T>() where T : class

    {
        return _objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public void Delete(object entity)
    {
        _objectContext.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return _objectContext.Connection;
    }

    public ObjectContext Context()
    {
        return _objectContext;
    }

}


public class ProjectEntityContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    #region IContextFactory Members


    public IObjectContext Build()
    {
        EntityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter entityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter = new EntityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter(new EntegraContext());
        entityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter.Context().CommandTimeout = 180;
        return entityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter;

    }

    #endregion
}
```

The code above is from the common implementation. Below is the create new employee code. Commit statement from code below, executes `SaveChanges()` method of `EntityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter` class mentioned above.

```
public void CreateEmployee(ICreateEmployeeCommand command)
{
    using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(ContextFactory))
    {
        _deptDao.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;

        Department dept = _deptDao.Get(command.DepartmentId);

        //Code below creates new employee object & assigns all the properties 
        // eg. Name Address Department from command object
        Employee emp = GetNewEmployeeObject(command, dept);

        //Code below calls SaveChanges method from EntityFrameworkObjectContextAdapter above
        unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}
```

& the Entity:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Employee()
    {

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
......
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `Insert`(new entity create) codes

Comment: Sorry, may be I won't be able provide an exact implementation. But, its pretty much straight forward. If its a Employee model. I have Employee e = new Employee() & have assigned all the properties. It has complex properties as well. Like e.Department = (Code to retrieve Department object). Will this help?

Comment: @SelimYıldız would you still require the exact code?

Comment: Yes please add your exact insert code.

Comment: And also your entity model.

Comment: @SelimYıldız I have edited my question to add as much as code possible. Please see if that is helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205488/discussion-between-selim-yildiz-and-jay).

Comment: @SelimYıldız Sure

Comment: start converting your `ObjectContext`  to just `DbContext`... then `_objectContext.InterceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault().Database.Log = x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);` would be `_dbContext.Database.Log .....` and this should be remove from `SaveChanges` and placed where the class is instantiated!, you should not be setting the log method on every `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @Seabizkit Yes, I added the log statement to trace the SQL statements. I will remove it for prod. Thanks.

Comment: awesome jay...Just an FYI, but DbConext and SaveChanges is a transaction on its own, so you could replace all the `using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork...` with `using (new ProjectNameContext... ` and instead of `Commit` just call SaveChanges, all im saying it you may want to rebuild your wrapper classes for working with your entities into more of a current EF6 way... making use of DbSet<> more...

Comment: @Seabizkit I will definitely work on your suggestion of replacing object context. As, I have also heard of its going to be obsolete soon with new EF. However, I am using the UnitOfWork wrapper around EF because I need to register few Events which will be called based on the success/failure of SaveChanges.

Comment: @SelimYıldız Thanks for your help in chat. I was missing to add the newly created entity to the EF context. After I did that, I see "Insert into " statement being generated. I will have to research how the same code might have worked for EF4.